# Foundation and Wordpress blank spaces

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

Anyone has an idea about the **blank spaces** that I'm getting in a while loop with wordpress using foundation framework?

```
    <div class="large-8 columns">

    <?php query_posts(array('category_name' => 'revista', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'posts_per_page' => 9 )); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="boletin large-4 columns" style="min-height:1px;">       

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>   

        </article>              

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div><!-- /large-8 -->

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>
```

Here's the page (please use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to see the latest version)

http://www.aoa.cl/revistas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason this happens is that your tiles does not have equal height.
you can use [Foundation Equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html) to fix that. and leave the code has you have it. I would still change the large to small and have

```
<article class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns">
```

to achieve better responsive results.
Foundation is mobile-first. Code for small screens first, and larger devices will inherit those styles. Customize for larger screens as necessary.

If you wish to have just three columns both on mobile and desktop do the followings:
I am adding a row every three lines. also changed large to small (large screens inherit small much better than small inherit large).

```
<div class="small-8 columns">
<?php $count=0;?>
<?php query_posts(array('category_name' => 'revista', 'paged' => get_query_var('paged'), 'posts_per_page' => 9 )); ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if ($count % 3 == 0): ?>
    <div class="row">
    <?php end_if; ?>
        <article class="boletin small-4 columns" style="min-height:1px;">       
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>   

        </article> 
    <?php if ($count % 3 == 2): ?>
    </div>
    <?php end_if; ?>  
    <?php $count++; ?>           

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- /small-8 -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to answer my question, you made me see where was my mistake, altough I didn't use your solution because it didn't work the the adding of the row every 3 articles (don't know why), but I found a solution and I'll be testing the row adding in the next few days.

Thanks again! :)